# Как узнать город расположения пользователя?

Tags: java, android, геолокация, google-api

Разрабатываю приложение, и мне нужно узнать город пользователя, чтобы взять с сервера нужную инфу. Прикрутил Google Location API, всё по [инструкции](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), только у меня это делает сервис. Я пользуюсь методом `getLocality()` объекта [Address](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/Address.html), который возвращает `String`.

Так вот, какую именно он возвращает String'у: на английском или на языке страны, в которой пользователь находится?

Comment: Ну это же вовсе не сложно проверить?

Comment: Безусловно. Но приложение слишком сырое, чтобы даже запуститься. Я тесты пишу пока по методике TDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Надеюсь поможет понять.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986530/why-my-app-doesnt-get-address-after-change-in-language)
Возвращаемый результат зависит от языка, который выбран в данный момент.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения так, чтобы он был самодостаточным.

Comment: Ответ исчерпывающе покрывает вопрос, так как вопрос стоял не в проблеме написать часть программы, а в понимании, что можно получить при разных локализациях. "Так вот, какую именно он возвращает String'у: на английском или на языке страны, в которой пользователь находится?"

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы наши коллеги, попадая на этот вопрос из поисковика, находили бы решение сразу, то есть без перехода в англоязычное сообщество, прочтение вопроса, ответа и их понимание.

Comment: Мысль понял. Вполне согласен, хотя и думаю, что знание примитивного английского должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

никто Вам лучше не расскажет об **Google Location API** лучше их спецификации

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location